# Html.ActionLink resolve controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

This line is in a MVC.Net 4.0 Razor view :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Name Of File", "OpenDocument", new { path = Model.Document.path })
```

However, the controller of this view (let's call it FileController) does not have any function named "OpenDocument".

Another controller (let's call it DocumentController) do have the function "OpenDocument".

On local run (visual studio), something magically "resolve" the controller to use and it work. However, on another server it crash because it does not found the function inside "FileController".

From my understanding of @Html.ActionLink, if you do not specify the controller name, it take the controller of the Form... am I wrong?

What configurations in an MVC.Net Application could do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, If you are using the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object%29) which takes only the link name, action name and the route values, It will look for that action name inside the current controller for which the current view is rendered for.

But you can use [another overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29) of `Html.ActionLink` where you can explicitly specify the controller name as well.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    object routeValues,
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

So your code to generate the link will be

```
@Html.ActionLink("Name Of File", "OpenDocument", "Document",
                                               new { path = Model.Document.path },null)
```

Comment: Thx, Yes I know. That would solve the problem. Im just wondering how can the application jump to another controller just like that?

Comment: `Html.ActionLink` will generate the markup for the anchor tag with the `href` value pointing to the path (which you pass to the method as controller name,action name etc)

Comment: I got it. FileController inherit from DocumentController... Thx for answering my first question!

Answer (score 0):

i am pretty sure ActionLink doesn't perform a submit so basically you need to specify the controller to be recognize. Someone correct me if am wrong.

Usually i use action link with ajax to send my data.